# How to use the phrase "from something fame"?

Tags: word-usage

Can the phrase be used to describe someone very popular? Can I say Beyonce from Spice Girls fame? 
Or should the person being described be a little less popular than the performance, like Kyle Gass from Tenacious D fame?
Also, are these sentences formal or informal?

Comment: 'Of' not 'from'

Answer (score 1):

The "sth" in your title is very confusing - what it that supposed to mean?

Anyway, from a grammar/semantics point of view you can use "of `<group/film/tv-show name>` fame" even if the group/film/tv-show isn't very well known, OR if the person in question is very famous (Beyonce wasn't in the Spice Girls, by the way).  There's no problem with it as a choice of words, as a way of explaining who someone is.

But, if the person is very well known, or much more well known than the group/film/tv show then explaining who they are **in terms of** that group/film/tv show is redundant and pointless.  It would make more sense to do it the other way round, e.g. to say "Did you like Destiny's Child?  You know, that group that Beyonce started off in."  This is just an example which assumes that Beyonce is now more well recognised as a reference than is Destiny's Child.

So, there are no **rules** about when you can use that phrase concerning the person's fame, but there are situations where it's a bit pointless.